# Limit eager load / relationship. Fetch three items from each relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Let's say a category have many products.

I wish to load all product categories, and then load three products for each category.

How would this be possible in Laravel 5? It seems impossible.

In other terms, I wish to limit an eager load.

I have tried with this:

```
        $categories = Category::with([
            'images',
            'products' => function($query) {
                $query->take(3); // THIS does NOT work...
            }
        ])->get();
```

It produces this output:

```
select * 
from `products` 
where `products`.`category_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') limit 3
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I add a relationship that extends the original one.

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'Products' );
}

public function firstProducts() {
    return $this->products()->limit( 3 );
}
```

Then I can call.

```
$categories = Category::with(['images','firstProducts'])->get();
```

There are probably other ways that you can achieve this. You could look into scopes, but for a quick solution, this works in tinker.

Comment: that should be:
    public function firstProducts() {
    return $this->products()->limit( 3 );
}

I was copying from my own code.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Not Jeff.

Comment: @drunkenPeacock How am I supposed to use the following line ```$categories = Category::with(['images','firstProducts'])->get();```

when using fractal transformers in apis?

Comment: It won't work for eager loading because it limits all results, not per group.